# Is Psalm 74:13 prophetic of the future or a reference to the past? Was that part of the process of taming the chaotic abyss?

Tags: genesis, psalms, creation

> Psalm 74:13You crumbled the sea with Your might; You shattered the heads of the sea monsters on the water.  https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16295/jewish/Cha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ps 73 in the Hebrew Bible is the same as Ps 74 in the English Bible.  This Psalm naturally falls into several sections:

- V1-3 is a lament over the apparent rejection of Israel by God
- V4-7 is a recounting of how Israel's enemies have desecrated the land and the sanctuary/temple
- V8-11 is a record of Israel's enemies boasts and arrogance
- V12-17 is a hymn of praise to God by recounting His almighty acts
- V18-21 is an attempt to remind God of His covenant promises to Israel
- V22-23 is a plea to God to defend Israel again

The OP asks specifically about V13 which is part of the 4th section as enumerated above.  This fourth section has multiple allusions to God's earlier acts of greatness that the Israelites liked to rehearse to show how great YHWH really is.  These are:

- V12: "God is my King" is a reminder of much earlier teaching in places like 1 Sam 8:7, 8, 24:6, 2 Sam 19:21, 1 Chron 28:5, 29:23, 2 Chron 9:8, 13:8, Ps 5:2, 44:4 that clearly taught that despite their earthly leadership descended from David, Israel's real king was God alone.
- V13a: "divided the sea" is possibly an allusion to both the creation acts on the second day where God separated the waters above from the waters below; and the separation of land from the sea on the third day of creation; and the dividing of the waters when Israel crossed the red sea.
- V13b & V14a - "sea creatures" appear to be allusion to God's power over the elements and creatures.  They may also be an allusion to Egypt as in several other places such as: Ex 15:13, Isa 27:1, 551:9, Eze 29:3, etc.  This is made more probable by the allusion to Israel's escape from Egypt mentioned above.
- V14b: the desert in association with dividing the waters makes the Exodus appear in the writer's mind again.
- V15: "dried up the ever-flowing rivers" appears to be an allusion to Israel at the end of their wilderness wanderings when they crossed the flooded Jordan river
- V16: "established the moon/light and the sun" is an allusion to God creative acts on day 4 of creation week.
- V17 "borders of the land" is an allusion to the separation of land and sea on day 3 of creation week - compare Job 26:10, 38:8, Ps 33:7, Prov 8:29, etc.

Thus, the hymn of praise in V12-17 recounts God's mighty acts and miracles of the past.